# My UPS shipping method is not working in wordpress project

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fedex, ups, usps

I have created one `woocommerce` project.I used three type `shipping method plugins` for that project.that are

1. ups
2. usps
3. FedEx

Here `Usps` and `FedEx` are working fine.But `ups` is not working fine.when i give country,stare,zip code it's showing

```
               There doesn‘t seem to be any available shipping methods. Please        

                  double check your address, or contact us if you need any help
```

I got some values as an  array. that showing

```
                     UPS post response
            WooCommerce UPS packages1.00FailureHard10002The XML document is well formed 
           but the document is not validAccessRequest/AccessLicenseNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if you have a SOAP client installed on your server. In WooCommerce click "System Status" and next to Soap Client you may see  "Your server does not have the SOAP Client class enabled - some gateway plugins which use SOAP may not work as expected." . I recommend create a backup of your database and files firstly, then install soap client